# Properties of Nonparametric Test Statistics $B$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, binomial-distribution, nonparametric

### Given

Consider the upper tail $H_0: \theta \leq 0 \,\,\, \text{vs} \,\,\, H_a: \theta > 0$  sign test with the test statistic
$B = \sum_{i=1}^n{\psi_i}$ where $\psi_i = \mathbb{I}(Z_i > \theta)$, where
$\mathbb{P}(\psi_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z_i > \theta)=p$. With the assumption that the $n$ observations are iid, answer the following questions.

### Questions

1. Show that $B$ has binomial distribution and specify its parameters.

   - The equation given for $B$ makes me think it's the test statistic for the `SIGN.test` in ${\tt R}$, but I don't understand the notation: $\psi_i = \mathbb{I}(Z_i > \theta)$, where
     $\mathbb{P}(\psi_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z_i > \theta)=p$
   - My guess is that $\mathbb{P}(\psi_i=1)=\mathbb{P}(Z_i > \theta)=p$ is saying that the probability of $\psi_i$ being $1$ is $p$, and then I need to relate $\mathbb{P}(Z_i > \theta)$ to $\mathbb{I}(Z_i > \theta)$ in order to show that $B$ has a binomial distribution?
2. Write down the null distribution of $B$.

   - <strike>I'm not familiar with the term *null distribution*, but I suspect *null* indicates something similar to the term *null model*, which is the model based solely on $\beta_0$ --- Perhaps the *null distribution* is the distribution based only on one of the parameters of $B$?</strike>
   - Upon further reading, it looks like the *null distribution* is the distribution under the assumption that $H_0$ is true. Since the test statistic $B$ is (*supposed to be*) binomial, I would guess that I just need to write $B$ as $B\overset{iid}{\sim} \text{Bernoulli}(n, p)$, where $n$ is the sample size and $p$ is as given?

### Note

- The $\mathbb{I}$ should be a $1$ with two lines, but SO wouldn't let me use `\mathbbm{1}`.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide! I don't just want answers, I want to understand how to find the answers.

Comment: That there are five questions here makes it too broad for our format.  Especially with self-study questions we recommend you focus your post by explaining what steps you have taken towards solving a single clearly articulated question and where you are stuck.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your feedback; I have edited my question to narrow the scope of what's confusing me.

Comment: "*we recommend you focus your post by explaining what steps you have taken towards solving a* ***single*** *clearly articulated question*". While several parts look like a better fit for self-study type questions, this still appears to be a laundry-list of questions rather than focusing on one issue.

Comment: @Glen_b I've narrowed down my question and provided some more of my thoughts. My key question is how to show that $B$ has a binomial distribution, which requires making sense of the formulas that are given.

Comment: $\mathbb{I}$ is an [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function). What's the distribution of $\psi_i$ in general? What is it under the null?

Comment: So, $\mathbb{I}$ is an indicator function (sometimes called an indicator variable). The notation $\psi_i = \mathbb{1}(Z_i > \theta)$ is saying that $\psi_i$ will be $1$ when $Z_i > \theta$, and $0$ in all other cases. Thus, we can represent $B$ as

$$B = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \psi_i \hspace{1em} \text{where} \hspace{1em} \psi_i = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \texttt{if} \,\, Z_i > \theta \\ 0 & \texttt{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Clearly, $B$ has a binomial distribution, with parameters $n$ and $p$ (number of trials and probability of success for each trial, respectively).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Show that $B$ has binomial distribution and specify its parameters.

$\mathbb{I}$ is an indicator function (sometimes referred to as an indicator variable). The notation $\psi_i = \mathbb{I}(Z_i > \theta)$ is saying that $\psi_i$ will be $1$ when $Z_i > 0$, and $0$ in all other cases. Thus, we can represent $B$ as

$$B = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \psi_i \hspace{1em} \text{where} \hspace{1em} \psi_i = \left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1 & \texttt{if} \,\, Z_i > \theta \\ 0 & \texttt{otherwise}\end{array}\right.$$

Clearly, $B$ has a binomial distribution. Binomial distributions have two parameters: the number of trials/observations, $n$, and the probability of success for each trial, $p$. Both $n$ and $p$ are given in the problem description.

> 2. Write down the null distribution of $B$.

The null distribution is just the distribution of the test statistic under the assumption that $H_0$ is true:

$$B \overset{iid}{\sim} {\tt Binom}(n, p)$$